# Find out which radio button is selected using Selenium (implemented as li)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have the below HTML. It's a small window with 3 radio buttons. Its implemented as a ul with 3 li elements. Below code clicks on the div inside the li and is selecting the radio button:

```
WebElement v = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/div[1]"));
JavascriptExecutor jsb = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsb.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", v);
```

How do I find out which of the three radio button is clicked? I want to open this screen again and be able to tell which one of the radio buttons is selected.

[image: HTML[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcwtb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't a lot of info in your question. I can suppose that the image with the interested html is when "none" is selected. If you notice, when a radio button is selected, the class name is **`"icon icon-dot-circle-o"`**.

Otherwise, the class name is "icon icon-circle-o".

You could use this info in order to understand which button is selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is what I missed.

Comment: @njosep Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `HTML` you shared, it's pretty much evident none of the `radio button` is selected initially. So your first question `How do I find out which of the three radio button is clicked?` doesn't seem to be a valid question. We should be able to select/click on any/all of the `radio button` through `Selenium` at our disposal.

Now, once you have selected a radio button, if your requirement is to validate if the correct `radio button` was selected or not you can use the following code block :

```
    List<WebElement> radio_options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='rc-diolog-body']//ul/li/div[not(@class='icon icon-dot-circle-o')]"));
    for(WebElement option:radio_options)
        {
            if(option.isSelected())
            {
                System.out.println(option.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
                break;
            }
        }
```